# No setter/getter for Firebase objects

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

This is my Java class:

```
public class OnlineMatch{

private FacebookUser firstplayer;
private FacebookUser secondplayer;


public OnlineMatch(){

}


public OnlineMatch(FacebookUser firstplayer, FacebookUser secondplayer) {
    this.firstplayer = firstplayer;
    this.secondplayer = secondplayer;
}

public FacebookUser getFirstplayer() {
    return firstplayer;
}

public void setFirstplayer(FacebookUser firstplayer) {
    this.firstplayer = firstplayer;
}

public FacebookUser getSecondplayer() {
    return secondplayer;
}

public void setSecondplayer(FacebookUser secondplayer) {
    this.secondplayer = secondplayer;
}
```

}

I can create objects correctly and uploaded to Firebase. The db structure is as follow:
[image: Screenshot taken from firebase panel control]

Then I try to print the values of my OnlineMatch objects (Kotlin code):

```
val match = dataSnapshot.child("multiplayer").getValue(OnlineMatch::class.java)
            if(match!=null){
                System.out.println(match)
            }
```

Here I get this output on the Android Studio console:

9548-19548/app.simone W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for -KqV44f4FUxV8ZDuqL4Y found on class app.simone.multiplayer.model.OnlineMatch

08-01 19:14:38.816 19548-19548/app.simone W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for -KqV3sAPXPcYrtr61cDy found on class app.simone.multiplayer.model.OnlineMatch

08-01 19:14:38.816 19548-19548/app.simone W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for -KqV2BGH7Z-Y9RxnPGpt found on class app.simone.multiplayer.model.OnlineMatch

Answer (score 1):

Your code is asking for *everything* under `multiplayer`, which includes all of the OnlineMatch objects you pushed there previously.  You can see from the error message that it's trying to find a setter or field for the push ID `-KqV44f4FUxV8ZDuqL4Y` that it found just under `multiplayer`  If you want to get a single OnlineMatch object, you're going to have to dig into the objects in the push IDs under `multiplayer`.  So this should give you something:

```
dataSnapshot.child("multiplayer/-KqV44f4FUxV8ZDuqL4Y").getValue(OnlineMatch::class.java)
```

In any event, you'll need to have the push ID of your choice, or discover them from the children of the snapshot and build a new snapshot from that child.

Comment: Thanks for helping me Doug, but I am still in trouble. Certainly I cannot have every push ID because they are automatically generated by Firebase. I just need to get an array of OnlineMatch, in the same way as I upload them to Firebase. This is the code I use for uploading them on Firebase db:   `code fun createMatch(match: OnlineMatch) {
        var database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("multiplayer")
        val matchList = database.push()
        matchList.setValue(match)
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Doug Stevenson, your answer was useful to me.
I created an array of strings where I save the key and then I iterate over the child for each specific key:

```
override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {

            // Get Post object and use the values to update the UI
            val match = dataSnapshot.children
            var keysArray = KeysHandler()
            if(match!=null){
            // saving keys into an array
                for (data in match){
                    keysArray.addToList(data.key)
                }

            // saving an OnlineMatch object into another array
               repeat(keysArray.list.size){ i->
                   val onlineMatch = dataSnapshot.child(keysArray.getElement(i)).getValue(OnlineMatch::class.java)!!
                   requestsUsers.add(onlineMatch)

               }

                // updating GUI
                updateRequests()
            }

        }
```